# Виджет не отображается

Tags: java, android, виджет

При добавление виджет на мгновение появляется и сразу пропадает. Раньше у меня все работало, но после переустановки приложения виджет перестал работать. Я откатил на старую версию, но все равно не работает. Я поудалял весь код, который как-то может помешать работать виджет, но безуспешно.
Код виджета:

```java
package ---.----.-------.---;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 * App Widget Configuration implemented in {@link wdgetConfigureActivity wdgetConfigureActivity}
 */
public class wdget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = wdgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.wdget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


        // Create an Intent to launch MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, wdgetConfigureActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        // This is needed to make this intent different from its previous intents
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:/"+ (int)System.currentTimeMillis()));

        // Creating a pending intent, which will be invoked when the user
        // clicks on the widget
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //  Attach an on-click listener to the clock
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            wdgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

Конфигуратор виджета:

```
package ---.-----.----.---.--;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * The configuration screen for the {@link wdget wdget} AppWidget.
 */
public class wdgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "duck.duck.go.search.wdget";
    private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";
    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    public wdgetConfigureActivity() {
        super();
    }
    static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
        prefs.apply();
    }
    static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null) {
            return titleValue;
        } else {
            return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        }
    }

    static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId);
        prefs.apply();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.wdget_configure);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        final Context context = wdgetConfigureActivity.this;
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context,  wdget.class);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
        String widgetText = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(99999999));
        for (int mAppWidgetId: appWidgetIds) {
            saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, widgetText);
            wdget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);
        }
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Виджет:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Glance.AppWidgetContainer">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#8600FF00"
        android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: зачем вам активность настроек если она закрывается? Проверьте правильность пути настройки в xml

Comment: путь настройки в xml корректный

Comment: Активность настроек еще не очень доделана

Comment: @Style-7 помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос

Comment: уберите с активности конфигурирования код в onCreate который обновляет все виджеты и попробуйте сделать какую-нибудь кнопку по которой виджет будет добавляться